# Can we do ProxyTunnel and redirect to a different port?

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server, proxy, ssh-tunnel, reverse-proxy

Learn from internet that we can tunnel SSH over HTTP(s) [[reference1]](http://www.nurdletech.com/linux-notes/ssh/via-http.html) [[reference2]](http://dag.wiee.rs/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/)

Once apache server is setup

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyVia block
    AllowCONNECT 22
    <Proxy *>
        # Deny all proxying by default ...
        Require all denied
    </Proxy>
    <Proxy 127.0.0.1>
        # Now allow proxying through localhost only
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

on client side we just need to have some extra config like below

```
host home80
   HostName myserver.com
   ProxyCommand proxytunnel -q -p myserver.com:80 -d 127.0.0.1:22
   Port 80
```

However for my case, the destination port is keep changing. (e.g above destination port is 22)

i do not want to ask end-user to keep changing their config, will be good if somehow i can redirect "127.0.0.1:22" to "127.0.0.1:xxx"

any thought how i can achieve that?